# How to redirect stdout to webfront with Python SimpleHttpServer

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I redirect stdout to the web in a SimpleHTTPServer in Python?

When the user calls the API, the server invokes an external function that outputs progress information to the console. I'd like to see that information in the browser as well.

Here is what I have so far.

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn
import threading
import argparse
import re
import cgi
from getDataV3 import magicHelper
import urllib
import base64
import sys




class HTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    tool = magicHelper(u"gfksdjs")


    def do_OPTIONS(self):           
        self.send_response(200, "ok")       
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS')
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization")

    def do_HEAD(self):
        print "send header"
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_AUTHHEAD(self):
        print "send header"
        self.send_response(401)
        self.send_header('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm=\"\"')
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        global key
        ''' Present frontpage with user authentication. '''
        if self.headers.getheader('Authorization') == None:
            self.do_AUTHHEAD()
            self.wfile.write('no auth header received')
            pass
        elif self.headers.getheader('Authorization') == 'Basic '+key:
            if None != re.search('/api/v1/check/*', self.path):
                recordID = self.path.split('/')[-1]
                self.tool.setMasterlist([urllib.unquote(recordID)])
                self.tool.useCaching = False
                self.tool.maxRecursion = 1
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
                self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS')
                self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization")
                self.wfile.write(self.scraper.startCrawl()) 
                self.end_headers()
            else:
                self.send_response(403)
                self.send_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                self.end_headers()
        else:
            self.do_AUTHHEAD()
            self.wfile.write(self.headers.getheader('Authorization'))
            self.wfile.write('not authenticated')
            pass


        return

class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True

    def shutdown(self):
        self.socket.close()
        HTTPServer.shutdown(self)

class SimpleHttpServer():
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.server = ThreadedHTTPServer((ip,port), HTTPRequestHandler)

    def start(self):
        self.server_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.server.serve_forever)
        self.server_thread.daemon = True
        self.server_thread.start()

    def waitForThread(self):
        self.server_thread.join()

    def addRecord(self, recordID, jsonEncodedRecord):
        LocalData.records[recordID] = jsonEncodedRecord

    def stop(self):
        self.server.shutdown()
        self.waitForThread()

if __name__=='__main__':
    key = base64.b64encode('xxxxx:yyyyy')
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='HTTP Server')
    parser.add_argument('port', type=int, help='Listening port for HTTP Server')
    parser.add_argument('ip', help='HTTP Server IP')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    server = SimpleHttpServer(args.ip, args.port)
    print 'HTTP Server Running...........'
    server.start()
    server.waitForThread()
```